# Non existent image files are not being handled by PHP as they should due to ngnix configuration

Tags: php, htaccess, images, url-rewriting, nginx

I am currently building a web application. In order for it to work properly I wrote this rule:

```
  location / {
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
      expires 168h;
      add_header Pragma public;
      add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";

      rewrite ^(.*)$ /libraries/render.php;
    }
  }
```

It is working for URLs with non-existent files like this: `http://test.test/test` but not for a non-existent image: `http://test.test/test.png`

I have a second rule that might be effecting images:

```
 location ~* \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png|ico)$ {
    expires 168h;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
  }
```

But I'm not sure how that would prevent the rewrite rule from triggering.  It's all the extensions in this rule that are not getting forwarded to `render.php`
When I remove this rule (by commenting it out) all extensions except `.png` work. This is very strange.

This is my entire config:

```
server {
  rewrite_log on;

  # IPv4
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;
  # IPv6
  # listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
  # listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;

  server_name test.test;

  # SSL
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/private/ssl-bundle.test.test.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/test.test.key;
  ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

  root /var/www/test;

  index index.php index.html index.htm;
  try_files $uri $uri/ $uri/index.php $uri/index.html $uri/index.htm =404;
  disable_symlinks off;

  location / {
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
      expires 168h;
      add_header Pragma public;
      add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";

      rewrite ^(.*)$ /libraries/render.php;
    }
  }

  location = /config.inc.php {
    internal;
  }

  location /cache/ {
    internal;
  }

  location /libraries/ {
    internal;
  }

  location /images/ {
    internal;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

    # With php5-cgi alone:
    #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    # With php5-fpm:
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }

  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
  }

  location ~ /\.sh {
    deny all;
  }

  location ~* \.html$ {
    expires -1;
  }

  location ~* \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png|ico)$ {
    expires 168h;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
  }

  # Rewrites

  rewrite ^(?<filename>.+\.(?<type>css|js))$ /compress.php?file=$filename&type=$type;
}
```

Comment: When you say "working" for `/test` but not `/test.png` are those real files that are not supposed to be served by *render.php* or the other way around?

Comment: These are both files that do not exist and that should be served by `render.php`. `/test` is being served by `render.php` but `/test.png` isn't.

Comment: Is it just `.png` image files that are not being forwarded to your php, or are other file types also problematic?

Comment: And just to make sure I'm understanding it, if you remove the "exists" condition so that *all* requests get served by PHP, then the *.png* URL gets handled correctly?

Comment: It's all the file extensions that being are being caught by the last location statement.

Comment: I can't test right now. Sorry.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller if i remove the if statement it still won't get handled by `render.php`.

Comment: That is what I figured.  I edited your question quite a bit to incorporate these comments.  The title doesn't point the finger at that if statement anymore.

Comment: For further testing, if you remove the `gif|jpe?g|png|ico` config section, then the png file gets handled correctly?

Comment: I noticed that. Thank you. Also commenting the image location did not help!

Comment: I managed to get this to work by moving the exiting image rule away from the root since this is possible due to my folder structure. I'm still not very happy with this "solution"!

Comment: I thought that you said removing that rule didn't help?

Comment: It surprised myself too!

Comment: Should I go into more extensive testing?

Comment: This is probably worth a read: http://blog.pixelastic.com/2013/09/27/understanding-nginx-location-blocks-rewrite-rules/  It appears that nginx will apply the `location /` rule last (despite that it comes first).   From that document it looks like it shouldn't *stop* after applying the image rule, but based on your experience it may be doing so for some reason.

Comment: For the purposes of this site it would be best if you submitted your "moved the rule to a different directory" as an "answer" to get it out of the list of "unanswered" questions.

Answer (score 1):

So after some trial and error I came up with a working solution that I'm not quite happy with. But at least it works.

Since all "real" images are located in `/includes/` or subdirectories I simply rewrote the rule for the images.

So this

```
 location ~* \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png|ico)$ {
    expires 168h;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
  }
```

Has been turned into this

```
 location ~* ^/includes/.+\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png|ico)$ {
    expires 168h;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
  }
```